# Automatic click with Selenium, using By.XPATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Do you see this little blue logo in the image below? Using WebDriverWait I would like to automatically click on this blue logo, in order to open the list of those who have left the likes.

[image]

I used By.XPATH., More precisely: `//*[@id="jsc_c_z"]/span[1]/span/span/div` , but it doesn't work. NOTA :I've noticed that the IDs and ranges on this page look suspiciously obfuscated and so maybe they won't necessarily be the same every time. So maybe I don't think id = "jsc_c_z" that will be reliable. **You may need to resort to using `aria-labeld` of the attribute on the target element div.**

My code is:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jsc_c_z"]/span[1]/span/span/div'))).click()
```

This instead is the link I would like to open https://www.facebook.com/FranzKafkaAuthor/posts/3985338151528881.

IMPORTANT: Maybe you have to enter with the Facebook login, but who does not want to do so will post a screenshot

PART 1 (UPLOADED)
[image]

PART 2
[image: enter code here]

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you update the question with the text based HTML of _likes_, _hearts_ and _count_ elements?

Comment: @undetected Selenium I only need the html of likes, not hearts and more. The html of the image is that of the blue like button. What do you need to see?

Comment: I wanted all the three for comparision only to get rid of the language barrier as the DOM text is non-english

Comment: @undetected Selenium I state that I discovered that if you click on the blue logo of the likes or the red logo of the hearts, the result is the same, because it will open the list of all those who have put a like or a heart or a reaction. I think I have found the html point you need. It is the part that is above that of the screenshot that I attached to the question. I added it in my question by writing "PART 1"

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
//span[@data-hover='tooltip']/span
```

When I was checking this, I couldn't find the div tag you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work. I wrote so WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//span[@data-hover='tooltip']/span"))).click(). Do you have any other ideas? Thanks